# Cascading of Kendo Dropdownlist with json object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a cascade of dropdowns in which change in the countries  will get states and bind to another dropdown which shows states.
I have checked documentation available in the kendoui website in which they have documented the way of cascading
using it's Events(CascadeFrom and so on.) but I do not want to do in this way.
As it is a double trip to database . First after loading the page, it binds countries(Calls database and get countries) and then 
it binds states after country is changed.

But I have done in a different manner. I bind Countries Dropdownlist
on page load so I saved one trip that is made to database for loading the
countries after page is loaded but I wonder If I can call the change of
countries dropdown in the following way and then bind states by json object.

This is countries dropdown which is binded successfully in view page

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Country)

                                      .DataTextField("Text")

                                      .DataValueField("Value")

                                      .BindTo(Model.CountriesTemp)

                                      )
```

Below is States list which will get record on the basis of change in countries dropdown.

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.State)
                                      .DataTextField("Text")
                                      .DataValueField("Value")
                                      .BindTo(Model.States))
```

For Binding Countries and states with page load, I have done this in controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
  public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            RegistrationModel Model = new RegistrationModel();

            Model.CountriesTemp = new SelectList(ObjService.GetCountries(), "CountryID", "Country_Name");
            Model.States = new SelectList(ObjService.GetStates(), "Id", "StateName");
    return View(Model);
        }

            public JsonResult GetStatesForCountry(string CountryId)
        {
            RegistrationService ObjService = new RegistrationService();
            var StatesList =ObjService.GetStatesForCountries(Convert.ToInt32(CountryId));
            return Json(new { JsonStates = StatesList });
        }  
}
```

This is my model::

```
public SelectList CountriesTemp { get; set; }
 public SelectList States { get; set; }
```

I have binded successfully both of the dropdowns , Now I want to do cascading for which I have written below script in my view page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Country").change(function () {
        var val = $("#Country").val();
        $.post("/Home/GetStatesForCountry", { CountryId: val }, function (Response) {
            var States = $("#State").data("kendoDropDownList");

        });
    });
});
```

And the function "GetStatesForCountry" is already defined in above controller but I am confused for how to use the returned json object and bind the kendodropdownlist which shows "states".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the state drop down list then set the data source returned from it as follows:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#State").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.setDataSource(Response.JsonStates);
```

**Further info:**

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-setDataSource

Comment: Hi. It has started binding the new data(states) that comes after the change of Country but unfortunately it is showing undefined in all the options. Do you have any idea on that too?

Comment: I am able to do this by doing the below code.
$.post("/Home/GetStatesForCountry", { CountryId: val }, function (Response) {
            //var States = $("#State").data("kendoDropDownList");
            //States.setDataSource(Response.JsonStates);
            $("#State").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "StateName",
                dataValueField: "Id",
                dataSource: Response.JsonStates
            });

        });

Comment: @sweetie nice one, sorry just seen your comments now. :)

Answer (score 4):

I am able to do this by using below code. The above answer was taken as reference.

```
$.post("/Home/GetStatesForCountry", { CountryId: val }, function (Response) {
            //var States = $("#State").data("kendoDropDownList");
            //States.setDataSource(Response.JsonStates);
            $("#State").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "StateName",
                dataValueField: "Id",
                dataSource: Response.JsonStates
            });

        });
```